# Getting an Expression is invalid inside an 'Include' operation, since it does not represent a property access

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am trying to include related records from a child table, in an EF Core query, but am getting this error:

> The expression 'i.SiteToSiteItems' is invalid inside an 'Include' operation, since it does not represent a property access: 't => t.MyProperty'. To target navigations declared on derived types, use casting ('t => ((Derived)t).MyProperty') or the 'as' operator ('t => (t as Derived).MyProperty'). Collection navigation access can be filtered by composing Where, OrderBy(Descending), ThenBy(Descending), Skip or Take operations.

I have research solutions and came up with two pages, which I'm sure I've followed to try to correct the error. Here is the parent table, SiteToSite (I'm removing unrelated properties):

```cs
[BindProperties]
public partial class SiteToSite
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Site to Site ID")]
    public int SiteToSiteID { get; set; }

    public virtual IEnumerable<SiteToSiteItem> SiteToSiteItems { get; set; } = null!;

}
```

And here's the child table (with unrelated properties removed):

```cs
[BindProperties]
public partial class SiteToSiteItem
{
    // PROGRAM
    // moving LotNum to an item object.
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Site to Site Item ID")]
    public int SiteToSiteItemID { get; set; }

    // Foreign key to SiteToSite table
    public int SiteToSiteID { get; set; }

}
```

Now here's one of the results I found to try and help me with this issue:
https://entityframework.net/include-multiple-levels

That link includes multiple levels of includes. I'm not trying to do that. This is a single level of includes.

Another resource I found to help me with this issue is this one:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/eager

Here's the code where I get the error in a service I've written:

```cs
public IList<SiteToSite> GetSiteToSitesById(int id) 
{
    var result = _context.SiteToSite.Where(s => s.SiteToSiteID == id).Include(i => i.SiteToSiteItems).ToList();
    return result;
}
```

I've tried changing the declaration in the SiteToSite class from `IEnumerable<SiteToSiteItem>` to both `IList<SiteToSiteItem>` and `List<SiteToSiteItem>`. Nothing changes the result; I always get the same error.

I'm using VS 2022, .NET 6, in an ASP.NET MVC Core app.

Comment: The error message indicates (to me) that 'i.SiteToSiteItems' is not treated as **navigation** property by EF Core. This might happen if you put `[NotMapped]` attribute on it or use `Ignore` fluent method. I've seen many people doing this in attempt to "solve" Json serialization issues with circular references, but that's breaking the normal EF Core behaviors. Shortly, make sure you are not telling EF Core to ignore that  property in the not shown part of your code.

Comment: Ivan, you've hit on the issue! I was getting an error in the DbContext class, when launching the app. I can't remember where I saw it but I saw a recommendation of using Ignore on SiteToSiteItems. How should I better handle error 0x80131509 instead of calling Ignore() ?

Comment: See here [Related data and serialization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/serialization).

Comment: I went to the Related Data and Serialization link you provided. I'm not explicitly using Json.NET, nor am I explicitly using System.Text.Json, but I figure System.Text.Json, is being used, perhaps by implicit or global usings.  Now I'm getting another error, but it isn't related to this. Thank you for your help, I consider your advice as answering this question.